# Use VBA to open a form from a main menu where one of the fields is null/blank

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm new to VBA and beginning to understand the basics, however, I'm having trouble opening a form from the main menu (which is just a form without a record source) where one of the fields is null/blank. I'm using a button with an on-click event to make this happen.

I'm able to open a form by setting the field to a specific value to open all the records that have that value. For example, the below code works:

`DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Projects" , , , "Status='Active'"`

However, I have a notes field in a form and when that field is null/empty, I want it to display only those records. The other fields can be filled out.

I've tried the following:

(1) Loads a blank form as if I'm trying to add a new record

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Project", , ,"txt_Notes='Is Null"
```

(2) Gives me a "Run-time error '2450':"

```
If IsNull([Forms]![frm_Project]![txt_Notes]) Then
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Project"
Else
   MsgBox "Some text"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use equal sign with `Is Null`. Also, the solo apostrophe is not appropriate.

`DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Project", , , "txt_Notes Is Null"`

The second code is missing closing paren.

`If IsNull([Forms]![frm_Project]![txt_Notes]) Then`

However, cannot reference field of form that is not yet open. Need a way on main form (or open a 'search' form) for user to choose which criteria they want to use for opening form or report. Or if you don't want user to have any input, code needs to query the data source to see if any records meet the requirement. A DCount or DLookup domain aggregate function can accomplish that.

```
If DCount("*", "your table or query name", "txt_Notes Is Null") > 0 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Project", , , "txt_Notes Is Null"
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Project"
End If
```

This assumes empty string is not allowed in field. I NEVER allow empty strings in text fields. Null and empty string are not the same thing. If empty string is a possibility, code will have to be adjusted. To handle both Null and empty string: `"Nz(txt_Notes,'')=''"`

Comment: For `DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Project", , , "txt_Notes Is Null"` I get a popup window to "Enter Parameter Value" as if I'm doing a query search. If I hit okay or enter text, it loads a blank form. I get the same error with `If IsNull([Forms]![frm_Project]![txt_Notes]) Then`

Comment: I tried the `If` statement with DCount and DLookup and I get a "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '*'." Where would I add your suggestion for handling Null and empty strings with `"Nz(txt_Notes,'')=''"` ? (Sorry, I don't know the difference between the two). Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Use it in place of `"txt_Notes Is Null"`. Both versions work for me. Edit question to show attempted new code. Null means there is nothing, zilch, nada; an empty string is something. Null cannot be compared to anything because nothing is there to compare, not even to Null. This is why `Is Null` or `IsNull()` or `Nz()` must be used when testing for Null. http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html